# How do I add a horizontal scrollbar to a table in a div?

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

How can I add a horizontal scroll bar to a table that is inside a div?
Is there CSS solution for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will not be able to add a scrollbar to a table, but you can add it to a DIV containing your table.

For example:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
   <table>...</table>
</div>
```

Comment: div
  {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

Answer (score 7):

If you only want a horizontal scrollbar use overflow-x:auto; then set the width.

```
div
{
width: 300px;
overflow-x:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To add the scrollbar use overflow:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You have to add width to the table too:

```
table {
    width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tpDGE/

Comment: yhays the Answer   div
  {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
div {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: thats the answer
div
  {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }